# cyman mark two open souce code

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, google-chrome-app

This isn't a programming/coding question, but i figured you guys would know the most about it since the information about it on Google is scarce.

I have been using an app named Cyman mark 2 for a few weeks and it seems like a pretty good app, but I wanted to make a few changes to personalize it to me but i didn't know if it was open source. i did my research and found nothing. Does anybody know anything more about it?

Again, I'm sorry this isn't a programming related question but i figured you guys would be the most knowledgeable ones on this subject.

Comment: When you contacted the authors, through the Web site and email address found on [the app's Play Store listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyman.android), what did they tell you?

Comment: they tend not to reply. I've tried twitter facebook and email.

Comment: Then the code is probably not open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the creator of Cyman System - I can tell you that both Cyman Mark 2 and Cyman Mark 3x (for Chrome) are not open source right now.  They may be in future, we don't know.

PS - apologies for not being able to reply to all mail. I'm a lone developer and it's only in my spare time (I have a full time job). I reply to as many as I can.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can contact you faster than from the cyman pages? I'm starting a similar project(for personal use) but with similar functionality so it would be really helpful if i could clear some questions that come up as this goes on. I have finals currently but I'm starting on it in about a week. Also I find your work brilliant especially looking at how you handle this single handedly from designing to updating and adding new functions.

Comment: The fastest way is probably through Google+. Unfortunately I get a lot of mail which I try to go through whilst designing/developing, but hopefully I'll be able to hep out somehow.  Best of luck!